# Does a load on a charging solar system degrade the battery if the panels are producing more current than the load?

Tags: photovoltaics, solar

Let's say I have 1000 W worth of solar panels hooked to a 2 kWh battery system like the [Anker 767](https://www.anker.com/a1780?utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=us_anker_pps_conversion_search_A1780_purchase_ost&utm_content=A1780&utm_term=%7B19750921396%7D_%7B150388444470%7D_%7B650568854773%7D&gclid=CjwKCAjwov6hBhBsEiwAvrvN6PQmm_GA4A6IK0grGulrAUleAxqYm9b2bYnRzkw-9c0UPzpb3Zyl0RoC6LAQAvD_BwE). Let's also say that the panels are running at full clip and I have a 900 W load on the system.

Does the load degrade the batteries at all? Is the current actually going through the battery or is it bypassing the battery since it's less than the input voltage?

Comment: Does the Anker 767 even accept charge from a solar panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your questions depend on whether the battery charge management system is designed to handle that scenario.  So I'll answer to what *could* be done -- but I can't tell you what any particular piece of commercial equipment *actually does* -- it's your job as a shopper to find that out.

> Does a load on a charging solar system degrade the battery if the panels are producing more current than the load?

Only if the battery charge management system allows it.  While I can't tell you what *is* out there, I *can* tell you that it would be easy to design a battery charge system that makes sure that your batteries are topped off, and then only takes as much power as is necessary from the panel to drive the load, leaving essentially zero current to the battery.

> Does the load degrade the batteries at all?

Again, a good battery charge management system wouldn't let this happen, at least in your scenario where there's more power available than the load.

Conversely, if there's more load than power available from the panel, what makes a battery charge management system "good" depends on your needs.  Most people's "good" would be to draw the batteries down short of permanent damage and then (possibly after giving you a goodly amount of warning), shut off the system.  Some people's "good" would be to go ahead and destroy the batteries if you let it, while letting you know this is happening (presumably this would be the case if the battery was powering something life-critical).

> Is the current actually going through the battery or is it bypassing the battery since it's less than the input voltage?

You appear to be confused about current, voltage, and their relationship.  No, the load is not going to be powered by the batteries if there is an excess of power available from the panel.  In that case the load would get power straight from the panel, or the load would be attached to the battery, but the actual current would be split between the load and the battery.

Voltage has little direct relationship to this (although it's involved).

Answer (score 0):

### Solar systems need a way to shed supply power if the supply is greater than the load.

You cannot put current into a full battery.  I don't know exactly what happens in modern batteries, but nothing good.  A lead acid battery will boil out the water and fill your shed with hydrogen.  Your battery should be connected to a system that manages this for you.  Best battery life is charging/discharging **not** to/from full charge/discharge and this will be different by battery type.

You also can't throttle the photovoltaic output.  Some water turbines have this problem as well.  The power company can change generator output as required.

Typical solutions are to supply power to the grid or install a resistor bank.

Comment: PV panels can be left open circuit in full sun not like solar thermal panels which can get near 200 degrees C...

Comment: @SolarMike in open condition there would be no supply

Comment: @TigerGuy: exactly.  So any decent charge controller would simply let the voltage on the panels rise until no more power came from them than was needed.  In other words, there _is_ a way to shed supply, and it's dead easy.

Answer (score 0):

It can do if the circumstances are right. It generally means you have an active BMS that is expecting a very low rate of change for current and voltage on the load side and will make adjustments based on a reasonable sampling rate of say 1 kHz. And you have a DC load that expects a steady voltage supply and runs a current chopper at say 1 kHz, but the two aren't perfectly synced. You can end up with the BMS operating in bang-bang mode and having more current flowing through the battery than the load is actually drawing. Modern, low impedance batteries are far more suseptable than wet lead, which acted like a giant capacitor and added had a lot of damping to any high-frequency dynamics.

The link below shows the filter elements typical of a grid connected PV system with batteries that can be islanded. It is drawn from a document that describes the design strategies for designing the filters so that they work properly in all modes of operation. The performance of grid-tied PV systems is tightly regulated and there are quite of lot of problems cause by the increasing numbers of non-compliant grid-tied PV sources. All the components labeled in red and blue are filter components. They are grouped into three filter assemblies, and they have to be designed carefully to work with each other. Since they may live on separate components, that can be tricky for the DIYer

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s42452-020-2747-7/figures/1
[image]